# Android HTTPS requests, doubts on the correct usage

Tags: android, http, https, keystore

I tried to contact an https server with the following code:

```
HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(new HttpGet("https://www.google.com"));
```

and it works perfectly (it returns the google page and the status code 200 OK).

I also tried to contact the same server with the following one:

```
BasicHttpParams clientparams = new BasicHttpParams();
[... clientparams initializazion...]

SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

SSLSocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(clientparams, schemeRegistry);
HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, clientparams);
HttpResponse response = myClient.execute(new HttpGet("https://www.google.com"));
```

and this works perfectly too. I tried also with other servers and always it works.

Then, can someone explain to me when I need to use a SchemeRegistry to initialize an http client? And also, in which cases it is necessary to inizialize a SSLSocketFactory with a custom KeyStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it comes down to the certificate that the server is using on its SSL connection. If it is something Android recognizes due to being root CA (usually these will be certificates from the more common sources, like Verisign for example) then it should work like you have here.

On other hand, if there is a custom certificate, or something self-signed, or something from a source that is maybe smaller or not generally accepted as being secure, then you will have to create a custom keystore to manually deal with that certificate.

Google likely uses the former, which is why your code works already.

Also, I believe you can add

```
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", sf, 80));
```

to your code and it will cover http connections as well without causing any harm to your application.